# Spring Boot Unit Testing MockMvc behavior

Tags: spring-boot, rest, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I get different results while unit testing my UserController in a Spring Boot REST API.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userService;

    @PermissionUserRead
    @GetMapping("/user/{userName}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDetails> getUserByUsername (@PathVariable String userName){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.loadUserByUsername(userName));
    }
}
```

@PermissionUserRead is:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('user.read')")
public @interface PermissionUserRead {
}
```

I follow two different approaches
without MockMvc: this Test is running fine, getting 200 as expected

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@Tag("UnitTest")
public class UserControllerUnitTest {

    @InjectMocks private UserController userController;
    @Mock private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = "user.read")
    public void getUserShouldReturnUser(){
        String username = "testUser";
        UserDetails testUser = TestAssistent.createUser(username);
        when(userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username)).thenReturn(testUser);

        ResponseEntity<UserDetails> classUnterTest = userController.getUserByUsername(username);
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK,classUnterTest.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

And one using MockMvc: This one is getting 401 as Status, instead of the expected 200

```
@Tag("UnitTest")
@DisplayName("UserController Unit Tests")
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {

    @Mock
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userService;

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown(){
        reset(userService);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = "user.read")
    void validGetUserShouldReturnUser() throws Exception{
        String username = "testUser";
        UserDetails testUser = TestAssistent.createUser(username);

        when(userService.loadUserByUsername(username)).thenReturn(testUser);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/user/testUser"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Seems like I am doing something wrong, since in the MockMvc Test my authentication does not work properly? Maybe some can help me with an explanation what and how MockMvc is doing in this case?

I tried using different @WithMockUser variants with roles, usernames, etc. but nothing worked.

Most examples I found for Controller testing are using MockMvc and I guess it's like the standard, so would like to get it done using MockMvc, or is it "fine" to go by my other solution without using MockMvc? I am not experienced enough to tell if my testing without MockMvc would trigger everything correct for a Unit Test.

Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: With `@WebMvcTest`, you do slice testing (some beans or resources are not mocked) while with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` you simply mock every dependency.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your hints, with that in mind, I took further research and found I should apply my Security Context to the Test by @ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class) and add 
- @Autowired private WebApplicationContext context;
-@BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

Now it seems I pass Authorization, but I get 404 instead, so seems like my URL does not exist in the test.

Answer (score 0):

I started further investigations on @WebMvcTest and finally found a more fitting way for me to do tests on my controller, using "REST Assured".

https://rest-assured.io

My new Test, which is of course only a starting for my Testing:

```
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerMockMvcTest {

@MockBean
private UserDetailsService userService;

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@BeforeEach
void setUp(){
    RestAssuredMockMvc.mockMvc(mockMvc);
}

@Test
@WithMockUser(authorities="user.read")
void shouldReturnUser(){
    String username = "test";
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singletonList(
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority("user.read"));
    UserDetails testUser = new User(username,"password",authorities);

    Mockito.when(userService.loadUserByUsername(username)).thenReturn(testUser);

    RestAssuredMockMvc
            .given()
              .param("username",username)
            .when()
              .get("/api/user/{username}",username)
            .then()
              .statusCode(200);
}
```

}

Ressources I used:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rkoFTxJhNk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLtXe1wgSC8

So my answer is yes, Use MockMvc to be sure calling URL, like your code would and use "REST Assured", as for me it is very easy to set up.